# How do I ensure that a generator gets properly closed?

Tags: python, generator

Consider a library function with the following signature:

```py
from typing import Iterator

def get_numbers() -> Iterator[int]:
    ...
```

Let's look at some simple code that consumes it:

```py
for i in get_numbers():
    print(i)
```

Nothing interesting so far.  But let's say we don't care for even numbers.  Only numbers that are odd, like us:

```py
for i in get_numbers():
    if i & 1 == 0:
        raise ValueError("Ew, an even number!")
    print(i)
```

Now let's try an implementation of `get_numbers`:

```py
def get_numbers() -> Iterator[int]:
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
```

Nothing very interesting here.  The results of running our little `for` are pretty much what we'd expect:

```
>>> for i in get_numbers():
  2     if i & 1 == 0:
  3         raise ValueError("Ew, an even number!")
  4     print(i)
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: Ew, an even number!

Ew, an even number!
>>>
```

We'd get the exact same results if `get_numbers` had a simpler implementation:

```py
def get_numbers() -> Iterator[int]:
    return iter([1, 2, 3])
```

But let's instead suppose that `get_numbers` needs to remain a generator because it manages some resource.

```py
def get_numbers() -> Iterator[int]:
    acquire_some_resource()
    try:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
    finally:
        release_some_resource()
```

For our purposes, the resource we'll manage will just be text printed on the screen:

```py
def acquire_some_resource() -> None:
    print("generating some numbers")

def release_some_resource() -> None:
    print("done generating numbers")
```

Our output is still predictable:

```
>>> for i in get_numbers():
  2     if i & 1 == 0:
  3         raise ValueError("Ew, an even number!")
  4     print(i)
generating some numbers
1
done generating numbers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: Ew, an even number!

Ew, an even number!
>>>
```

But what if we can't use a simple `for` loop?  What if we want to ignore the first number, for example?  (Let's pretend that `itertools.islice` isn't a thing.)

```
>>> it = get_numbers()
  2 next(it, None)
  3 for i in it:
  4     if i & 1 == 0:
  5         raise ValueError("Ew, an even number!")
  6     print(i)
generating some numbers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
ValueError: Ew, an even number!

Ew, an even number!
>>>
```

Notice something?  We acquired our resource, as evidenced by the text "generating some numbers", but we never released it.

The right thing to do is to make sure the generator gets closed:

```
>>> it = get_numbers()
  2 try:
  3     next(it, None)
  4     for i in it:
  5         if i & 1 == 0:
  6             raise ValueError("Ew, an even number!")
  7         print(i)
  8 finally:
  9     it.close()
generating some numbers
done generating numbers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
ValueError: Ew, an even number!

Ew, an even number!
>>>
```

The problem with this approach is that this assumes that `get_numbers()` returns a generator, and thus has a `close` method.  But its signature doesn't promise that.  What if its implementation is the simpler one I gave earlier?

```
>>> def get_numbers() -> Iterator[int]:
  2     return iter([1, 2, 3])
  3 
  4 it = get_numbers()
  5 try:
  6     next(it, None)
  7     for i in it:
  8         if i & 1 == 0:
  9             raise ValueError("Ew, an even number!")
 10         print(i)
 11 finally:
 12     it.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'close'

'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'close'
>>>
```

So the *right* thing to do here is something pretty tedious:

```py
it = get_numbers()
try:
    next(it, None)
    for i in it: 
        if i & 1 == 0: 
            raise ValueError("Ew, an even number!") 
        print(i) 
finally: 
    if hasattr(it, "close"): 
        it.close()
```

I can wrap this up in a context manager to make it simpler, but it feels like I'm doing something the language should be doing for me, or at minimum, that the callee should be concerning itself with, not the caller.

Is there a simpler way to handle this?

Comment: I think the key difference is you instantiating the generator with `it = get_numbers()` instead of `for i in get_numbers()`.  In the latter option, the interpreter understands that you are done with the generator and thus releases it.  However in the former, the interpreter have no idea if you still plan to use `it`, so it makes sense for it to retain `it` in memory until explicitly told to close `it`.  I think this is exactly as it's meant to behave.

Comment: But the language doesn't offer me, as the consumer of some library, the means to determine whether or not I have to explicitly close `it`, nor does it offer the developer of said library the means to ensure that his generator gets closed.

Comment: You could  `del it`. The generator would be closed properly. (you may need a `gc.collect()` to be sure). @r.ook is right, it looks like a matter of variable scope.

Comment: The caller has to take some responsibility, because the language can't tell the difference between you being truly done with the iterator and you simply not using it after the last call to `next`. One way of doing that is to use a `with` statement, which explicitly brackets the use of the iterator.

Comment: IMO, in general a language aims to cover most of the use cases, and leave it up to the users to manage the edge cases.  Also when the code exits, the resource would be released either way so I believe this counts as a non-critical feature and therefore not implemented.

Comment: @chepner: `with` would be how I expect to deal with this situation, but generators and iterators don't typically implement the context manager pattern, so `with` results in `AttributeError: __enter__`.

Comment: Which is why *you* need to implement them.

Comment: Right, so like I was saying, I can write a context manager that implements the final approach above.

Comment: @r.ook: The resource is not guaranteed to be released.  For instance, if the program exits after raising the `ValueError`, then `release_some_resource` will never be called, because the generator will never be collection by the garbage collector.

Comment: You could also use the [contextlib.contextmanager decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) to manage a generator that requires resource management.  I believe this would be the intended approach.  As for why I said the resources gets released, in the case of an `open(...)` file, the file gets released after the script fails... though not properly released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As my comment mentioned, one way to properly structure this would be using the [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) to decorate your generator:

```
from typing import Iterator
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_numbers() -> Iterator[int]:
    acquire_some_resource()
    try:
        yield iter([1, 2, 3])
    finally:
        release_some_resource()
```

Then when you use the generator:

```
with get_numbers() as et:
    for i in et:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            raise ValueError()
        else:
            print(i)
```

Result:

```
generating some numbers
1
done generating numbers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 4, in <module>
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

This allows the `contextmanager` decorator to manage your resources for you without worrying handling the release.  If you're feeling courageous, you might even [build your own context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` function to handle your resource.

I think the key takeaway here is that since your generator is expected to manage a resource, you should either be using the `with` statement or always be closing it afterwards, much like `f = open(...)` should always follow with a `f.close()`

Comment: +1  What I like about this is that the callee essentially declares that it needs to be cleaned up, effectively moving some of this responsibility to the callee where it belongs.  What I _don't_ like is that it still requires cooperation between the callee and caller.  So, for instance, if this were an implementation of an ABC, the implementer couldn't choose whether or not it needed cleanup.  That's a detail that just can't be encapsulated away.  But that's just a limitation of the language at this point, and your answer is, I think, the _right_ way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to actually use the [`Generator` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator), as to properly signal that you are returning a `Generator`.

Comment: Embedding the generator in a wrapper function doesn't change the results in my testing.  I wouldn't expect it to.  The `it` variable in my example still holds a reference to effectively the same thing (a generator's `__iter__` method just returns `self`, AFAIK), so it gets garbage collected no sooner—which is to say still probably never, such as if the script exits.

Comment: Declaring the function as returning a generator helps to signal to the caller that it needs to close it, but I was hoping to avoid changing the signature, to cover the ABC implementation scenario and keep the fact that it's a generator a private implementation detail, since a generator is compatible with an iterator.  It seems that this isn't really possible.  So if that's the case, and the signature has to change, I like r.ook's idea of making it a context manager to enable the use of `with`.

Comment: @PDaddy you are right about the wrapper, I tested it with the wrong function. I will update the answer to just keep the `Generator` type as an option.